# I want to iterate over my Account[]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

so there is an Account[] which has Accounts and their related contacts.
Can i get contacts details like this?: if not then how can i access contacts details, without adding one more aura iteration tag

```
<aura:iteration items="accounts" var="acc">
    <p>Contact Name:{!acc.Contacts.Name}</p>
</aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one more iteration inside this which is `<aura:iteration items="acc.Contacts" var="con"> {!con.Name}  </aura:iteration>`